# How to use glmnet on a small sample?

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet

I'm analyzing a high dimensional data set `Z` with n=12 samples and p=61 parameters (the data is numeric and has no NA's). To do so, I'm using the glmnet package to compute Lasso estimators on the regression data (`Z[, j]`, Z`[, -j]`) for `j` between 1 and p. 
Therefore I'm choosing one column to be my observation, the other columns are my design (For those who are a little bit experienced in high dimensional statistics: I want to use Neighborhood Selection).

Seems to be easily done with the use of `cv.glmnet`, what is the case for bigger samples. But in this case, with n=12 samples, `glmnet` seems to mess up:

```
as.matrix( coef( cv.glmnet(Z[, -j], Z[, j], intercept=FALSE))[-1])
```

> Error in predmat[which, seq(nlami)] <- preds : replacement has length zero

This is the error I get, but this does not always happen. To study the error, I used to following `for`-loop

```
for (j in 1:p){
  print(j)
  as.matrix( coef( cv.glmnet(Z[, -j], Z[, j], intercept=FALSE))[-1])
}
```

The first thing that came in my mind, is that it is working for most of the `j`. But sometimes, like for no reason it does not for example `j=7`.
I repeated the loop and saw, that the `j`s that don't work, differ. Seems like the error is dependent on randomness.

```
set.seed(70)
for (j in 1:p){
  print(j)
  as.matrix( coef( cv.glmnet(Z[, -j], Z[, j], intercept=FALSE))[-1])
}
```

This confirms my guess. 
Therefore i think, that it has to do with the tuning parameter calibration. `cv.glmnet` uses k-fold cross validation. So my next guess was, that if `k > 12`, that there could be empty sets that occur when partitioning the data set. But setting `nfolds = 3` didn't solve the problem.

Do you guys know how to fix this problem?

Here is a minimal example of the problem:

```
library(glmnet)

set.seed(79)
data <- rnorm( n=62*12, mean=0, sd=1)
Z <- matrix( data, nrow=12, ncol=62)
set.seed(2)
for (j in 1:61)
{
     print(j)
     as.matrix( coef( cv.glmnet(Z[, -j], Z[, j], intercept=FALSE))[-1])
 }
```

In this case, we see that the procedure fails at `j=13`.
However, using another seed, we get no error:

```
 set.seed(1239340) 
 for (j in 1:61)
 {
     print(j)
     as.matrix( coef( cv.glmnet(Z[, -j], Z[, j], intercept=FALSE))[-1])
 }
```

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: I added a minimal example to the original post.